# How can I customize the text of a Facebook App Request in Android?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-3.0, facebook-requests

I already built a way for users to send requests to other users, to INVITE them to the android app I have.

The thing is, the receiver of the facebook notification, gets this default ugly text "John sent you a request" in it, and I want the notification to be something like "John invited you to try [Appname]".

I can't find any good answer in Facebook documentation(which by now I hate). This are the tutorials and docs that I followed:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/apprequests/?locale=es_LA

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/send-requests?locale=es_LA#step2

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/requests/v2.2?locale=es_LA

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I actually was testing this with a user that already gave my android-app permissions. 
All I had to do is test it with a user that never gave permissions to my app. This was actually already working.

If the user is new, the notification displays something like " X has invited you to try [app-name]"